# Is it possible to track the stack height / recursion depth reliably?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, recursion, stack-overflow

I'm trying to reliably keep track of my stack height in a certain portion of my program, in order to adaptively tune a machine learning algorithm.

Right now, my code looks like this:

```
private const int MaxStackHeight = 20;

[ThreadStatic]
private static int stackHeight;

...

try
{
    var currentHeight = Interlocked.Increment(ref stackHeight);
    var depthFactor = currentHeight / (double)MaxStackHeight;
    // Use `depthFactor` to limit the amount of branching & recursion at this depth by choosing simpler candidates.
}
finally
{
    Interlocked.Decrement(ref stackHeight);
}
```

I'm aware that using `Interlocked` with a `ThreadStatic` field isn't necessary, and I'm aware of [Constrained Execution Regions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/performance/constrained-execution-regions). However, this problem is very similar to the `Monitor.Enter`/`Monitor.Exit` problem, so I'm not confident that this can be solved with the use of CER's. For example, the solution for `Monitor` is using the `out lockTaken` parameter available on one of the `Monitor.TryEnter` overloads, added in .NET 4.  Is there a similar strategy for `Interlocked.Increment`?

Example solution for Monitor (.NET 4+):

```
var lockTaken = false;
try
{
    Monitor.TryEnter(handle, ref lockTaken);
}
finally
{
    if (lockTaken)
    {
        Monitor.Exit(handle);
    }
}
```

This works because the finally block is a Constrained Execution Region, and because the .NET Framework guarantees that the `out lockTaken` parameter will be accurately set.

I can resort to one of two alternatives if this is not possible.

- Pass the height of the stack on the stack (e.g. pass it along as a method parameter). This significantly increases the complexity of many, many methods in my codebase.
- At the root call-site, set `stackHeight` to `0` before and after calling the recursive portion (even in the case of an exception). This feels... bad.

So, *is* something similar possible for my use case, or do I need to resort to an alternative approach?

## Edit:

Best guess:

```
        var incremented = false;
        try
        {
            RuntimeHelpers.PrepareConstrainedRegions();
            try
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                stackHeight++;
                incremented = true;
            }

            // Use `stackHeight`
        }
        finally
        {
            if (incremented)
            {
                stackHeight--;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would keep the value before incrementing and calling recursively, and restore it when I need to, for example:

```
var currentStackHeight = stackHeight;
try {
  for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    stackHeight = currentStackHeight + 1;
    recurseDeeper();
  }
}
finally {
  stackHeight = currentStackHeight;
}
```